# time and venue for learning the puranas

Tags: vedas, puranas, upanishads

I found few puranas online and I really enjoy learning vedic stories/scriptures which contain not only a nice story in themselves but hidden with immense knowledge and wisdom. I wonder if it is a propaganda by the Pandits that we need to have certain types of asanas(one you put up with hay or *Kush*),  bath in the morning, wear special types of dressing to study the puranas or the upanishads. Are these rules necessary?(Like something bad would happen if not followed). I'd really like some insight into weather if these are customary or essential and possibly a reason behind them.

Comment: Your statement in the question - "**I'd really like some insight into weather if these are customary or essential and possibly a reason behind them**" may be inviting opinion based answers.  And, someone may Flag it for closing @justcode

Comment: The purpose of having bath before puja or pArAyaNa is to instill freshness on the mind.  Some experienced people take up studying Puranas, etc, after performing sandhyAvandanam or puja.  Soiled clothes are liable to carry bad odour, which if weared , will distract the mind.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv , what about the asan made of kush, we(us people) live in unpure material made structures like of cement, is it appropriate to read inside a building as such?

Comment: Asan made of kush or cotton or something else should give a comfortable feeling for remaining in the posture for longer periods.  The purpose of Asan is to that extent only.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv , do you know of any vedic texts that describe these sort of disciplinary rules?

Comment: Now a days, the popular ones are Guru Charitra, Shirdi Sai Charitra , Sundara Kanda, Durga Saptasati parayanas.  Do you want me quote rules given from one among those?

Comment: @srimannarayanakv , sure that would be really helpful, also links to where these could be bought would be even more helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following rules were prescribed by [Sri Kshetra Gangapur web site](http://www.srikshetraganagapur.com/shri-guru-charitra.asp) (Holy place where Sri Nrisimha Saraswati, an incarnation of Sri Dattatreya lived for major part of his life), for doing parayana of Sri Guru charitra.

These rules can be made applicable for parayanas of other Holy texts also, after making necessary adjustments.

> - It Must be read with **Complete Physical and Mental Purity** i.e at
>     morning after the bath with Fresh Mind with No worldly concern.
> - The Place of reading must be Cleaned and a ***Deepa must always be lit***
>     while Parayana.
> - One Should not Speak while reading and ***also maintain Brahmacharya***
>     during the Parayana Days.
> - E**ating of Onion, Garlic, Egg etc must not be done** and if possible one
>     must have food only once and Fast in the Morning or Night.
> - One Must **avoid Sleeping on the Bed** and can use mat on floor
> - After the Parayan Samapti one Should offer P**ooja to the Holy Book** and
>     perform Dampatya Bhojan (Brahman and Suvasini).

Comment: can you explain more about the Dampatya Bhojan, what does it mean?

Comment: @juztcode: dampatya indicates Husband and wife  and bhojan indicates meals.  Normally, an elderly brahmin couple will be invited in some areas for meals after completion of parayana.  In some areas some amount will be given as donation.  It depends upon custom.