# What should be the correct posture for reading/listening Hindu scriptures?

Tags: ramayana, bhagavata-purana

I have listened from my parents and other respected people that Bhagwat Geeta paath and Ramayana paath should be studied only at holy places. This question arises many times. So my questions are:

> What should be the correct posture for reading/listening Hindu scriptures?
>
> Is this violation of the rules to listen to these on sleeping bed?

Comment: I too have the same habit.i am not married but i had the same doubt since some time now. I hope someone answers.

Comment: I am talking about reading.Even the priest i know says that reading them as stories is okay at any time but as sanskrit slokas it needs some basic things like time and place even if its in home. But i too listen to them at night in youtube. Priest even said listening is preferable to reading for beginners, you know to not make mistakes in pronunciation. I teally think its not a big deal.i'll let you know abou it.

Comment: Please tell me why my question is closed? Due to some hesitation many people can't ask such questions to their gurus and other priests. I wants to know please help me

Comment: @Visheshreddy thanks for commenting mam. In Devi Bhgawat it is clearly mentioned about precision, before reading. I have clearly told in my question that I am sleeping with my hubby on the same bed. Should I listien these spritual lessons or not?

Comment: @sv. now I think I have made the necessery corrections, please have a look on this

Comment: Similar question was [answered here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/38012/3869).  Best posture would be to sit before the deity with folded legs, after bath, and to do pArAyana.  In respect of people, who cannot sit due to physical problems, or who cannot do pArAyana by themselves, another method is available for them, which  is called sravana.  sravana means, some other person will read out the text, after following prescribed methods of keeping oneself pure, and the person intends to get benefit will take comfortable position to him/her and listens to that recitation.@PriyaPandey

Comment: @srimannarayanakv thanks for this.